# What is the significance of 88.7?

Tags: steam, achievements, mirrors-edge

I have just completed Mirror's Edge and I am now going back through to locate all the courier drops. I've noticed that next to a lot of them is some graffiti. Several of the graffiti marks have mentioned 88.7.

[image: Screenshot of graffiti]

I assume this is a reference to the FM radio frequency but I can't seem to match it up to anything. As a side note I will try to find a better screenshot, one that I haven't accidentally shot.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: I have nothing to say except that Solar Fields is my favorite musician.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### 88.7 is a secret underground radio network.

On the Windows Phone version of Mirror's Edge, there is actually an [achievement for it:](http://www.trueachievements.com/Mirrors-Edge-Windows-Phone/achievements.htm)

> **I Heart 88.7**
>
> Find the pirate radio frequency graffiti

While the game never explicitly covers and talks about said radio station, despite the graffiti you can find around town, its most probable uses are for relaying messages to runners or perhaps an underground movement against the current government.

On the teaser websites for some Mirror's Edge content, 88.7 was often referred to in the source code on the website as a channel where Faith could communicate with the underground rebellion movement.

Comment: It isn't that secret, almost every radio can tune in to 88.7. I guess that it might be something like [Radio Londres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_Londres#Coded_messages) in WW2...

Comment: @Burgi In the context of the world that Faith lives in, I believe that perhaps radios are no longer in use by the government, and that radio channels only exist as a communications network between rebels.

Comment: @Burgi I was thinking secret as far as where the network is located and who operates it. And the objective isn't to hide the the ability to listen to the station but share it in an attempt to spread pro-rebel/anti-government propaganda. Hence the promotion via graffiti.

Comment: @Burgi "Allo london, allo london, this is nighthawk... "